# snRNA-seq Demultiplexing before or after QC

Tags: single-cell, quality-control, demultiplexing

I'm currently analyzing snRNA-seq data and have to demultiplex them using HTODemux in Seurat.

The question is : should I do my QC filters on my droplets before or after the demultiplexing ?

From what I can test, the QC filters actually is going to have an effect on the assignation to each sample, as you can see in the small summary data below

**Demultiplex, then QC :**

```
Cutoff for 2-2 : 104 reads
Cutoff for 2-3 : 242 reads
Cutoff for 5-2 : 80 reads
Cutoff for 5-5 : 78 reads

 Doublet Negative      2-2      2-3      5-5      5-2 
     347     1754     1182      960     1278      959
```

**QC, then Demultiplex :**

```
Cutoff for 2-2 : 109 reads
Cutoff for 2-3 : 194 reads
Cutoff for 5-2 : 83 reads
Cutoff for 5-5 : 74 reads

 Doublet Negative      2-2      2-3      5-5      5-2 
     426     1466     1066     1284     1302      936
```

As you can see, in the case of sample 2-3 we have a 25% difference in assignation, so I don't think we can completely ignore that.

To be clear, I understand why there's a difference (normalisation, clusterisation differences, quantiles differences), I am looking for best practices here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the end I took the decision to first do the QC and then Demultiplex, reasonning that the Demultiplex steps (normalisations, clustering etc ...) are probably cleaner this way, leading to a (I hope) better assignation